# When receiving a packet on my server it won't update the variable i extract from it

Tags: c++, sockets, server, network-programming, sfml

I am trying to setup a simple client/server where the client sends data (a string) over a TCP socket to the server and the server displays it.

The first time I do this, it works perfectly, the server receives the data from the client and displays the string as it should. However, even though I have my `.receive` in a loop always awaiting new data, it seems to not update the `sentence` variable I extract from it.

I have checked and the client is definitely sending new information, and the server seems to be receiving the packet but it is not updating.

Here is my server code:

```
int main() {
    std::string sentence;
    sf::Packet packet;
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    sf::TcpSocket client;


    // bind the listener to a port
    if (listener.listen(53000) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        cout << "error listening";
    }

    // accept a new connection

    if (listener.accept(client) == sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        cout << "accepted and working :";
    }

    while (1) {
        client.receive(packet);
        packet >> sentence;
        cout << sentence;
    }
    cin.get();

}
```

and my client sending the information:

```
sf::TcpSocket socket;

sf::Packet packet;
std::string sentence;


if (...) {
    packet << sentence;
    socket.send(packet);
    cout << sentence;

}
```

Comment: Did you check a status returned by the receive method?

Comment: hi, thanks i solved my issue by using packet.clear();

Comment: where did you add `packet.clear()`, it is interesting since the first statement in receive method is actually `packet.clear()`. See https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/fae3b65f0567f87fa9925cd42d28df15eb69e79c/src/SFML/Network/TcpSocket.cpp#L346